# AngularJS: Clearing an ng-href link

Tags: angularjs

Stumbled upon this [link on ng-href](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/zeNN7WGST7I) and am wondering about the same thing.

Is there a way to clear the href of an ng-href link? Null values do not work post 1.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah just have set whatever your return value is for ng-href to " " (<- there is one space between the quotes). It should work as expected then.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b6e4a71166c7f00f4140fd7ea8f0cd81b4487a3f), the preventing of empty value mainly targets to `<img src>` `<link href>` `<script src>`, but also incidentally prevents `href` of `<a>` from being empty which is valid value. I've written [a ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2755) for this.

Comment: Nice, lets hope for the best. Having to use ng-switches to disable links would be really annoying